# Как задать размеры диалогу через style?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-dialog, android-style

Я пытаюсь с помощью стилей сделать разные стили для разных цветовых тем в своём приложении.
Для этого я создал два стиля для диалогов и в стилях, соответствующих своей цветовой теме буду их указывать через `<item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/LightDialog</item>` 
Так вот цвет текста я настроил,но с размером проблема - диалог вылетает на весь экран.

[image: Пример диалога]

Я пытался и width задавать и `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>` задавать но диалог всё равно вылетает на фул экран.
Вот мой код,который вызывает диалог:

```
   private fun showWarningToRebootDialog(theme:Int) {
        val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        alertDialog
            .setMessage("Для изменения темы требуется перезапуск приложения")
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.apply) { dialog, which ->
                if (theme==R.id.dark_theme) {
                    saveInSP(THEME_COLOR, DARK_THEME)
                    goReboot()
                }
                else if(theme==R.id.light_theme) {
                    saveInSP(THEME_COLOR, LIGHT_THEME)
                    goReboot()

                }
            }
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel) { dialog, which ->
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
        alertDialog.show()
    }
```

Что сделать что бы диалог был стандартных размеров как ОС сама выводит их. И да, кастомный диалог это вариант решения проблемы,но я хочу знать как решить данную проблему путём стилей

Comment: `LightDialog` от кого наследуется?

Comment: не наследуется вообще на данный момент

Comment: Системные используют стили типа `Theme.***.Dialog` или `Theme.***.Dialog.Alert`, попробуйте от них тоже отталкиваться.